# add a class to <body> if in "capable" webapp on iOS 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and Ionic frameworks to develop a webapp for iOS 7.
I would to add a class to the body DOM element only when the page is loaded from the added-to-home webapp (which I set to apple-mobile-web-app-capable yes).

I'm trying to do it in this way: adding this javascript at the end of the head

```
if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone){
  $(".body").addClass("platform-ios7")
}
```

but it isn't working.
What would be the best way to do it?
I know AngularJS has ng-sstyle, expressions and filters, would be possible to achieve this with angular?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `if (typeof window.navigator.standalone !== 'undefined' && window.navigator.standalone) {...` has worked for me.

Comment: @steveax It isn't working too. I'm trying to contact the Ionic developers, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to know whether or not it's the IOS home screen anywhere in the code of the app (so not in any controllers or services), and you purely want the class for CSS reasons, then I think a small custom directive is the way to go.

```
app.directive('iosDetect', function($window) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
      if(('standalone' in $window.navigator) && $window.navigator.standalone) {
        iElement.addClass('platform-ios7');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Which you can then use on the body element (or, indeed any element):

```
<body ios-detect>
```

You can see the below plunkr for an example

http://plnkr.co/edit/zCPOUSLeykjsCmsfuxtR?p=preview